# Getting a key size of DSA/Elgamal certificate

Tags: dsa, elgamal-encryption, key-size

I've tried to get a public key size of DSA/Elgamal PGP certificate. Using the Cleopatra I find out that there is actually two public keys - one with `DSA` with key size `1024 bits` and the other `Elgamal` with `2048 bits`. 
Now my question is which of this key sizes is the actual key size for this certificate and more importantly, why?

Comment: Usually DSA is just used for signatures while El Gamal is used for decryption.

Comment: I mean, it could be both, display the certificate here in base 64 so we can be sure

Comment: I maybe figure it out. It's just because I use the Bouncy Castle library to get the size of the key size. But I expect to return a key size of El-Gamal algo, instead the DSA key size is returned. DSA in this case is a master key, however El-Gamal is a subkey. I think it's kind of related to this. :)

Comment: What does ‘actual key size’ mean—what is the metric of key size that is relevant to you?  Are you trying to find storage costs?  Estimate attack costs?  Estimate computation costs?

Comment: Note that PGP principals can have many different keys associated with them.  There's always one _primary_ key which is used to certify subkeys, but you might have (say) a primary certification key, an encryption subkey, a long-term signature subkey, a short-term email signature subkey, and an authentication subkey.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely likely that 1024 is the master key size as authentication and signing are usually the main purposes of PGP. The key used for encryption is generally valid for a shorter time and is therefore a subkey of the master key. So both 1024 and 2048 bit public keys are included in the PGP certificate.

Note that the key size for encoding the key will be larger and the key strength (compared to e.g. an AES key) will be much less.

Both 1024 and 2048 bit keys are rather small for common purposes. It is highly advisable to upgrade to larger, RSA based keys. For more information about key sizes and their strengths, please take a look at https://keylength.com.